# Using fullcalendar to open modals

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Is it possible to replace the `url` component of the event's array with a `data-target` so that users can open modals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use dayClick

```
dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view){
    $('#modal').modal('show')
}
```

or eventClick

```
eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view){
    $('#modal').modal('show')
}
```